# Branching off another branch in Git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, rebase

I have a bit of a unique issue with git. I accidentally branched off another branch (both local branches: Branch A & Branch B) and I have a remote branch that contains an MR for both of these.

Now one of the branches(branch A) doesn't contain a specific file (which branch B has) but every time I checkout master pull the latest changes, checkout branch A, and rebase master I lose all the local changes, and if I push those changes then on the remote branch the file within branch B (that's not on A - the file does not actually exist on branch A locally either) appears as the only change on the MR and I lose all the other files I actually committed & pushed. Has anyone had this before? Or know how I can fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: What is local changes ? Have you commited this changes ?

Comment: Can you show the exact commands which you have executed, plus the output of `git log --oneline --decorate --graph branchA branchB master`? Even better if you can share the repository directly (but I understand if that's not possible)